# I need help in design patterns for an iOS webservice client

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, architecture

I want to implement a webservice client in iOS which uses SOAP and XML for requests/responses. 
My view starts the initial businnes logic (a user presses a button or something and initiates some businnes method called method_A).

So I have a class with method_A and this method checks if the user is logged in etc and then starts the request asynchronous via the SOAPConnector-class. So the UI is not blocked (asynchronous).
The SOAPConnector-class takes the XML and handles the requests. I use therefore NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection with sendSynchronousRequest.

The response is sended back to a Response-class which takes the response. This class then wants to parse the response XML. Therefore I use an extra class called XMLManager which uses NSXMLParser to parse the xml. But again here we need a delegate which gets the parsed xml. And again after parsing I have to implement an extra method to give back the parsed xml to the first class which initiated the request.

I am really wondering if this is the right way. The first problem is asnychronous request to not block the UI (the first callback). The second problem is the parsing where I am forced to use the delegate (the second callback). This results in a lot of classes and methods and I doubt this is the right way. The classes' only purpose is to manage the delegate and async problems. So I am asking for any suggestions and help how to solve this. Do you know some good design patterns to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some inconsistencies in the way you describe the design patterns you've selected:

> and then starts the request asynchronous

vs.

> I use therefore NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection with
>   sendSynchronousRequest.

---

That said, your approach seems sound.  Addressing the issues you've identified:

> I use therefore NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection with
>   sendSynchronousRequest.

Isn't that the purpose of using an asynchronous API?  If your `NSURLConnection` is really operating asynchronously, that issue should be covered.

> The second problem is the parsing where I am forced to use the
>   delegate

This approach does result in more classes, delegation, etc. but it conforms to best practices when it comes to testing.  If you are performing unit testing or other testing strategies (you are aren't you?) then testing in isolation is all the harder unless you breakdown this process functionally.

If you have access to the book [Test-Drive iOS Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774183) there is a great section on the best practices for consuming web services with a view toward testability.

Comment: The first class with method_A starts the request asynchronous to not block the UI. So at this point there are two threads. The UI and the rest for the request. Later on somewhere when it comes down into the class SOAPConnector, it sends the request synchronous, but it is still in the other thread (not blocking the UI).